# Put time (months/ years) in a proper sequential way on x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, bar-chart

I could not put time (month/year) in a proper sequential way on x-axis in ggplot although. I tried to address it based on prior posts eg using `unique` but couldn't fix it till the moment.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Used code:

```
library(dplyr);library(string)
#Original date format
#"10/1/2020" "5/1/2020" "9/1/2020" 
data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<-NULL
data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<-data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0
data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<-str_replace(data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, pattern = "/\\d+\\/", replacement = "/")
data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<-as.Date( data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0, "%m/%d/%Y")

data...lim<-subset(data, data$STOP.STATUS.afterFiscal.Year==1)
data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format <- factor(data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, levels = rev(unique(data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format)), ordered=TRUE)
levels(data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format)

data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<-format(data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, format="%B %d %Y")

df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format <- factor(df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, levels=unique(df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format))
data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format <- factor(data...lim$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, 
                                              levels=c( "4/1/2015", "5/1/2015","6/1/2015",
                                                      "7/1/2015", "8/1/2019","9/1/2015",
                                                      "10/1/2015","11/1/2015","12/1/2015",
                                                      #=========================
                                                      "1/1/2016","2/1/2016","3/1/2016",
                                                      "4/1/2016", "5/1/2016","6/1/2016",
                                                      "7/1/2016", "8/1/2016","9/1/2016",
                                                      "10/1/2016","11/1/2016","12/1/2016",
                                                      #=========================
                                                      "1/1/2017","2/1/2017","3/1/2017",
                                                      "4/1/2017", "5/1/2017","6/1/2017",
                                                      "7/1/2017", "8/1/2017","9/1/2017",
                                                      "10/1/2017","11/1/2017","12/1/2017",
                                                      #=========================
                                                      "1/1/2018","2/1/2018","3/1/2018",
                                                      "4/1/2018", "5/1/2018","6/1/2018",
                                                      "7/1/2018", "8/1/2018","9/1/2018",
                                                      "10/1/2018","11/1/2018","12/1/2018",
                                                      #=========================
                                                        "1/1/2019","2/1/2019","3/1/2019",
                                                      "4/1/2019", "5/1/2019","6/1/2019",
                                                      "7/1/2019", "8/1/2019","9/1/2019",
                                                      "10/1/2019","11/1/2019","12/1/2019",
                                                      #=========================
                                                      "1/1/2020","2/1/2020",  "3/1/2020",
                                                      "4/1/2020","5/1/2020",
                                                      "6/1/2020","7/1/2020","8/1/2020",
                                                      "9/1/2020","10/1/2020","11/1/2020"))

> ***Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [53] is duplicated***

data...lim<-subset(data...lim, select= c(STOP.STATUS.afterFiscal.Year, 
                                   StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, 
                                   OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps ))

df <- data...lim %>% group_by(StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format) %>% 
   count(OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps) %>% mutate(Percent = n / sum(n)*100)

> df
# A tibble: 217 x 4
# Groups:   StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format [70]
   StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps      n Percent
   <ord>                         <chr>                       <int>   <dbl>
 1 "         "                   FED/NIH/OTHER_GOV           11444   5.59 
 2 "         "                   INDUSTRY                    39241  19.2  
 3 "         "                   OTHER                      153153  74.8  
 4 "         "                   NA                            870   0.425
 5 "4/1/2015 "                   FED/NIH/OTHER_GOV               6   8.45 
 6 "4/1/2015 "                   INDUSTRY                       16  22.5  
 7 "4/1/2015 "                   OTHER                          49  69.0  
 8 "9/1/2015 "                   FED/NIH/OTHER_GOV               7   7.07 
 9 "9/1/2015 "                   INDUSTRY                       25  25.3  
10 "9/1/2015 "                   OTHER                          67  67.7  
# ... with 207 more rows


df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format <- factor(df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, levels=unique(df$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format))

p<- ggplot(df, aes(y = StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, x = Percent, fill = OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip()+ 
  labs(y = "Stoppage (month/year)", x = "Percentage",fill = "Organization class")
p+theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))


#################################### by number #############################################
p<- ggplot(df, aes(y = StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, x = n, fill = OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip()+ 
  labs(y = "Stoppage (month/year)", x = "Number",fill = "Organization class")
p+theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep the X-axis class as date and not `factor`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format<- as.Date(data$StopMonthYearNoneStop0, "%m/%d/%Y")

ggplot(data, aes(y = StopMonthYearNoneStop0_Format, x = Percent, fill = OrgClass_Combined.Gov_3gps))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip()+ 
  labs(y = "Stoppage (month/year)", x = "Percentage",fill = "Organization class") + 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

If you need to format X-axis you can then do it easily with `?scale_x_date`.

Comment: Thx for your efforts. I tried it but it gives me ````Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns
Backtrace:
  1. (function (x, ...) ...
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
  6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
  7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
  8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
  9. ggplot2:::scales_add_defaults(...)
 10. base::lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
 11. rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)```Any advice?

Comment: @MohamedRahouma  So it means you have duplicate column names in your data. You can rename/drop duplicate columns. If the error still persists can you edit your post to include `dput(head(data))` so that we have a reproducible example to work with?